# Docker build on Bluemix Containers can't find Dockerfile

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to build a docker image remotely with Bluemix using the following command:

```
cf ic build -t dude -f docker/production/Dockerfile .
```

However I consistently receive the error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 32.57 MB
Error response from daemon: Build aborted with error: "filename 'Dockerfile' not found"
```

Moving the `Dockerfile` to the root of the project initially looks like it is hanging but then does seem to succeed.

Per the [documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_native-docker.html) the docker build command is supported and thus I'd expect the `-f` option to also work.  Maybe this is not the case?

Any ideas or others who have managed to get this to work?  Here is the Docker version information:

```
# docker version
Client:
  Version:      1.9.1
  API version:  1.21
  Go version:   go1.4.3
  Git commit:   a34a1d5
  Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
  OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
  Version:      3.0
  API version:  1.20
  Go version:   
  Git commit:   
  Built:        2016-02-10T16:22:49
  OS/Arch:      Bluemix Containers/
```

Comment: What version of docker is installed on your Bluemix instance? (`docker version`)

Comment: @VonC, I've updated the question with the `docker version` information.  For now I've created a script that will temporarily move the right environment Dockerfile into the project root which works but is still annoying overall.

Comment: Is docker/production/Dockerfile a path relative to your current folder? If yes, it should be part of the docker run context.

Comment: It is and I'm with you, it should be a part of the run context!  In the case above I run the command in the project root with the Dockerfile at `./docker/production/Dockerfile`.  I'm thinking it is a Bluemix bug ... I just tried with Docker Toolbox and it worked no problem.

Comment: I agree, it looks like a bug. Does the issue persists if you anchor the path? `cf ic build -t dude -f ./docker/production/Dockerfile .`

Comment: Good thought, unfortunately no dice :(  It results with the same error.  Thanks for all of the ideas @VonC

Answer (score 1):

Reading the documentation at

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_cfic.html#container_cli_reference_cfic__build

I suppose that the -f option **isn't supported yet** by the *cf ic CLI* of **IBM Bluemix Containers**.
Anyway you have the opportunity of using **docker native commands** on Bluemix, as described here

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_ov.html#container_cli_ov

> Whenever possible, run docker commands as for example docker run
>   During login, copy and paste the environment variables that are provided in the terminal.
>   DOCKER_HOST sets the Docker host to IBM Containers.
>   DOCKER_CERT_PATH sets the location of the authentication keys for the IBM Containers plug in for Cloud Foundry.
>   DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY uses TLS and verifies the remote server.
>   Then, you can use the Docker CLI directly for the current session to run supported Docker commands. Some exceptions require the use of cf ic commands to perform tasks specific to IBM Containers, such as setting a namespace.

According to that, after login through *cf ic login*, you could switch your local runtime docker engine to Bluemix registry (and back) setting the values of

DOCKER_HOST
(and DOCKER_CERT_PATH/DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY, but these values won't change)

to the values suggested by the output of cf ic login (and to the original values to switch back to your local environment)

Comment: Hm, did this work when you tried it?  I just tried with using `docker` over `cf ic` and get the same error.  Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: I didn't tried, but switching to docker is supported.
What could be unsupported is the docker option, it will depend from
- Bluemix docker engine version
- Bluemix disabling specific docker options

Answer (score -1):

In the IBM Containers documentation, a list of all the supported and unsupported Docker options for cf ic commands is being worked on. This is an ongoing effort to compile, so there are still some options that are not included here yet.

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_cli_reference_native-docker.html#container_cli_reference_native-docker